# Flashing strings with threads

Tags: java, string, multithreading, applet

I'm trying to write a Java applet that will display a user-inputted String, it should then flash the string by switching between that and another one. I'm trying to use a thread to do this, but I'm new to those and Applets, I don't know what to do from here on out.

here's what I have so far:

```
public class FlashingLabel extends JApplet implements Runnable
{
String blank;
String input;
JLabel label; 
Thread t;



public void init() 
{
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter String", "Flashing Label",   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    blank=" ";

    t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void run() 
{
    while(true)
    {
        label=new JLabel(blank);
        add(label);
        this.repaint();
        label=new JLabel(input);
        add(label);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: DO NOT UPDATE THE UI FROM ANY THREAD other then the Event Dispatching Thread.  You will want to have a read of [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Never do anything within the Event Dispatching Thread that will block it (long running tasks or IO), it will make your application look like it's hung.
- Never create or update any UI component from any thread other then the Event Dispatching Thread
- There's no need create new `JLabel`s each time you want to update the message, simple use `JLabel#setText`.  You're code is currently adding two new labels on each loop through

For you're needs, a simple [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) will perform the task you are trying to achieve.

```
public class FlashApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                add(new FlashPane());

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
    }

    public static class FlashPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final String[] MESSAGES = {"Bad Boys", "What you gonna do"};

        private Timer flashTimer;
        private JLabel label;
        private int messageIndex = -1;

        public FlashPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add((label = new JLabel()));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            flashTimer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    messageIndex++;
                    if (messageIndex >= MESSAGES.length) {
                        messageIndex = 0;
                    }
                    label.setText(MESSAGES[messageIndex]);
                }
            });
            flashTimer.setRepeats(true);
            flashTimer.setCoalesce(true);
            flashTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
            flashTimer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

You might like to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

To make your code safe an idea would be to wrap it in invokeLater (or do some crazy thread safe thing of which I know not).

```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
   public void run()
   {
    label=new JLabel(blank);
    add(label);
    for(int i =0;i < 4;i++)
    {
       label.setText(blank) ;

       try{
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(...){
         }
       label.setText(input);

    }
   }
```

Add your label, it is blank initially.. sleep for a second (change to suit your needs), then set it to your input. Last time I did something like this, it worked and it was on the main UI thread.

Comment: So we're just going to ignore the fact that the update requests are begin executed outside of the **Event Dispatching Thread**